# Circuit to make toggle switch off temporarily pull low before going back high again

Tags: circuits, toggle-switch

I have a toggle switch that outputs 5V when it is on.  I would like to make the off functionality momentarily pull to 0V and then go back to 5V.  So basically the off switch isn't really off, it just sends a short 0V wave and then goes back to 5V.

Comment: What does the 5V output from the toggle switch do?

Comment: You are looking for a "falling edge detector".  There are various implementations using discrete logic gates and flip-flops, but as @BruceAbbott is trying to get to, this sounds like an XY problem.

Comment: The output runs to the RST pin on an ESP8266.  The switch is basically to wake it up from a deep sleep.   The ESP8266 is pretty limited on how it can wake from deep sleep.  In reality, it won't be a switch but a lid being removed that turns off the circuit and causes the ESP8266 to wake.  I didn't want to wait for the lid to be put back on before waking up.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a falling edge circuit is the right direction.  Thank you vir.

I am actually going to switch chips to the ESP32-S2-MINI-1, since it is cheaper than an 8266 and it's possible to wake from deep sleep from GPIO inputs.